# How can I run Xdebug in WSL. Are there any other options?

Tags: php, ubuntu, phpstorm, windows-subsystem-for-linux, xdebug

Trying to set up WSL without Docker. Created in `C:\Users\istmn\\.wslconfig`

```ini
[wsl2]
localhostForwarding=true
```

Added rule

```
New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "WSL" -Direction Inbound -InterfaceAlias "vEthernet (WSL)" -Action Allow
```

I take the value from **/etc/resolv.conf**

```
nameserver 172.23.128.1
```

I substitute it in **/etc/hosts**

```
172.23.128.1    wsl.host
```

Editing configs **/etc/php/7.3/mods-available/xdebug.ini**

```ini
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.start_upon_error=yes
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
xdebug.client_host=wsl.host
```

I open the project via PhpStorm `\\wsl$\Ubuntu\var\www\tr-archive` This is a Laravel project, so I didn't set up Apache. I start `php artisan serve` server at `127.0.0.1:8000`

I do Xdebug validation test in PhpStorm settings:

[image]

I receive such a message and I can't connect to Xdebug:

[image]

Comment: @LazyOne, Thank you for your help. Now I'll look at the differences in the configs. But, it seems, I use everything for debugging v3, except for xdebug.remote_autostart=1

Comment: @Vladimir You have `xdebug.start_with_request=yes` for Xdebug 3, which is the same as `xdebug.remote_autostart=1` from Xdebug 2.

Comment: And also, I think you can just set `xdebug.client_host=localhost`, as that's what the debug info from PhpStorm hints at?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe someone will need my experience sometime.

In general, I don't use docker, I just installed wsl and ubuntu for myself. The hosts automatically register the variable host.docker.internal (I didn't pay attention to it because I don't have a docker). It is necessary to use it in the configs of the debag
**xdebug.client_host=host.docker.internal**